# Как пропустить часть кода в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я еще только начинаю изучать Python и никак не могу понять как пропустить часть кода. Допустим у меня есть вот это:

```
print ('Начало')
for j in 'hellow  world':
    if j == 'w':
        break
    print(j*2, end = '')

l = [12, 34, 54, 67]
print ('\n',l)

print('\n',l, sep='')
print('123')
print(*'123')
print(*'123', sep=', ')

l = [1, 4, 45, 56, 78]
i = 0
while i < 4:
    print (l[i])
    i += 1
print ('Конец')
```

Я хочу, чтобы у меня выводилось только Начало и Конец. Как это сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, воспользоваться условным оператором `if` и ввести дополнительную переменную, которая будет будет показывать нужно ли вывести всё или пропустить часть кода.

```
print ('Начало')
print_all = False # флаг, показывающий нужно ли выводить всё
if print_all:
    for j in 'hellow  world':
        if j == 'w':
            break
        print(j*2, end = '')

    l = [12, 34, 54, 67]
    print ('\n',l)

    print('\n',l, sep='')
    print('123')
    print(*'123')
    print(*'123', sep=', ')

    l = [1, 4, 45, 56, 78]
    i = 0
    while i < 4:
        print (l[i])
        i += 1
print ('Конец')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое